# Assembly shift right with carry in?

Tags: nasm

My class is using Nasm assembly and I was trying to figure out different ways to shift, we know the instructions shr/sar, shl/sal, ror, rcr, rol, rcl. But would I shift right and set the leftmost bit to whatever I want.
For example:

I have 11010011, and shifting right would produce _1101001 cf=1,
is there a shift in which I can carry in a number to the leftmost bit?
Thanks!

### edit:

My only thoughts are using bit-wise operations and if the leftmost bit isn't what I want I can flip it using the not operator.
For example the number ends up as  1 1101001 and I wanted 0 1101001,

1 1101001 & 01101001 = 01101001 
or, 
0 1101001 | 11101001 = 11101001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to simply set the bit to what you want using AND or OR operations.

If you want the high bit set to 1, use `input OR 1000000`.
If you want it set to 0, use `input AND 01111111`.

The remaining bits will be unchanged.

Comment: I wasn't thinking clearly enough, SHR will bring in a 0 so  if I want 11111111 instead of 01111111 just add 10000000 or 2^7